# Mockito NullPointerException Invoking equals on InvocationMatcher

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm new to Mockito, having trouble with an error when trying mock a third-party class.

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at MockitoTest.equals(MockitoTest.java:34)
at org.mockito.internal.invocation.InvocationMatcher.matches(InvocationMatcher.java:58)
at org.mockito.internal.stubbing.InvocationContainerImpl.findAnswerFor(InvocationContainerImpl.java:75)
at org.mockito.internal.handler.MockHandlerImpl.handle(MockHandlerImpl.java:87)
at org.mockito.internal.handler.NullResultGuardian.handle(NullResultGuardian.java:29)
at org.mockito.internal.handler.InvocationNotifierHandler.handle(InvocationNotifierHandler.java:38)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.MethodInterceptorFilter.intercept(MethodInterceptorFilter.java:51)
at MockitoTest$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$cde393a2.getSomethingElse(<generated>)
at MockitoTestTest.test(MockitoTestTest.java:19)
```

Mockito is invoking the equals method on this mock, which does not have some of its private members set. Code:

```
public void test() {
    final String something = "something";
    final String somethingElse = "somethingElse";

    MockitoTest mt = Mockito.mock(MockitoTest.class);
    when(mt.getSomething()).thenReturn(something);
    when(mt.getSomethingElse()).thenReturn(somethingElse);
```

The class being mocked is defined something like this:

```
public class MockitoTest {

private final String something;
private volatile String somethingElse;

public MockitoTest(String theThing){
    something = theThing;
}

public String getSomething(){
    return something;
}

public String getSomethingElse(){
    return somethingElse;
}

@Override
public final int hashCode() {
    return something.hashCode();
}

@Override
public final boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(!(o instanceof MockitoTest))
        return false;
    return something.equals(((MockitoTest)o).something);
}
```

}

It's plain to see that the NPE coming from equals() is happening because the constructor is not run and 'something' is not set.

My questions: Why is this happening on the second when() call? Is there a way to prevent the equals method from being invoked? Am I doing something wrong?

Note: the example above was contrived to show the error happening. The real class I'm trying to mock is in a third-party library that can't easily be changed. It's not trivially constructed, and it requires a type that is not visible outside the third-party package. Short of writing my test in their package is there something else I can do to mock it, as attempted above?

Comment: You sure it's on a "when" that the error is occurring? Without the no-arg constructor, I don't think the variables will initialize and thus they will be null, but I'm not sure why you'd get an NPE with the when() statements since that wouldn't matter.

Comment: Oh, and if you're mocking a concrete object, you could try spy() and the Mockito syntax of doReturn("asdfasd").when(foo).doThing().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that your problem is that `equals` and `hashCode` are `final` in the class you're trying to mock.  Mockito needs to override those methods; so this class may be unmockable.

In any case, mocking a third party class is usually a bad thing to do.  Is it possible for you to refactor your application so that the third party class is wrapped?  Your wrapper should expose only the methods that you need to use.  When you write your unit test, you can just mock the wrapper.

Comment: Good info. I didn't realize Mockito needs to override equals and hashCode. It must fail silently in this case, and problems manifest elsewhere. I ended up declaring the tests in the third-party package so I could access the hidden types and construct the object in question. 
Thanks for the input.